# Unloading broken assembly Assets/Firebase/Plugins/Mono/Firebase.Database.dll, this assembly can cause crashes in the runtime

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to unity and am currently working on a project using firebase as my database platform.

My error is:

> Unloading broken assembly 
>   Assets/Firebase/Plugins/Mono/Firebase.Database.dll, this assembly can
>   cause crashes in the runtime.

I have no idea how to solve it, can I get any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have faced this kind of situations. You can try this method.

Go to Inspector Search

Firebase.Database

Disable  the FirebaseDatabase.dll under /Firebase/Plugins/Mono/

and enable remaining Firebase.Database.Dll(2 will be there)

Enable the  Firebase.Database Dll in

/Firebase/Plugins/

Try this method. You can solve that issue.